# Makefile to render all targets of all .Rmd files in directory

Tags: r, macos, makefile, knitr, r-markdown

My aim is to have a universal Makefile which I can copy into each directory where I have an RMD file, which will, upon calling `make` in this directory, render all targets defined in all .Rmd files in this directory.

The Makefile below works for only renders the last file as expected. I am sure I am doing something simple wrong.

How do I have to modify the Makefile so that it does what it is supposed to do?

Also: when I run `make` a second time, all files are generated again, although no SOURCE files changed.

I have the following Makefile:

```
SOURCES=$(shell find . -name "*.Rmd")
TARGETS_pdf=$(SOURCES:%.Rmd=%.pdf)
TARGETS_html=$(SOURCES:%.Rmd=%.html)
TARGETS_nb_html=$(SOURCES:%.Rmd=%.nb.html)
TARGETS_docx=$(SOURCES:%.Rmd=%.docx)

default: $(SOURCES)
    $(info Generating defined targets from $(SOURCES))
    @echo "$< -> $@"
    @Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('$<', output_format = 'all')"

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGETS_pdf)
    rm -rf $(TARGETS_html)
    rm -rf $(TARGETS_nb_html)
    rm -rf $(TARGETS_docx)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `make` it executes the first rule it finds. In your case it is `default`. It checks then if this file exists. If it does not, the script is run, which is supposed to generate the target file (`default`). Your script does not do that. That is why next time make runs, it starts all over again. If the file exists, the script does not need to be run.

What you could do is this:

```
SOURCES=$(shell find . -name "*.Rmd")
TARGET = $(SOURCES:%.Rmd=%.pdf) $(SOURCES:%.Rmd=%.html) $(SOURCES:%.Rmd=%.nb.html) $(SOURCES:%.Rmd=%.docx)

%.docx %.nb.html %.html %.pdf: %.Rmd
    Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('$<', output_format = 'all')"

default: $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET)
```